# Simple Perl for-loop error

Tags: perl

```
for ($i=1; $i<=3; $i++) {
    if ( @user$i[3] >= 4.0 ) {
        print "first";
    } elsif ( @user$i[3] < 4.0 and @user$i[3] >= 2.5 ) {
        print "second";
    } else {
        print "third";
    }
}
```

It doesn't work

I want same function below code

Could you give me some help

```
if ( @user1[3] >= 4.0 ) {
     print "first";
} elsif ( @user1[3] < 4.0 and @user1[3] >= 2.5 ) {
     print "second";
} else {
     print "third";
}

if ( @user2[3] >= 4.0 ) {
    print "first";
} elsif ( @user2[3] < 4.0 and @user2[3] >= 2.5 ) {
    print "second";
} else {
    print "third";
}

if ( @user3[3] >= 4.0 ) {
    print "first";
} elsif ( @user3[3] < 4.0 and @user3[3] >= 2.5 ) {
    print "second";
} else {
    print "third";
}
```

Comment: Please check this[URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be handy to lift your content quality up

Comment: (1) For array `@arr` an element is `$arr[3]`, with `$` since it's a scalar.  (2) Don't try to set variable _names_ in running code. It is _not_ recommended.  You can _always_ solve the problem in other, good, ways. For example, try this.  An array `@users` can have _references_ to arrays.  No worries about users 1,2,... -- just iterate through `@users`.  See tutorials on [Array of arrays](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html) and on [complex data structures](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html).  Array indices start at `0`. Always **use warnings;**. Read up on the language, this is too basic.

Comment: _It doesn't work_ doesn't make any sense. Telling what are you expecting and what are you getting would be more helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Use References to iterate over the different arrays.

[perldoc perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) - perl references

[perldoc perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) - perl data structure cookbook

```
#/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @user1 = ( 1, 2, 3, 4 );
my @user2 = ( 4, 3, 1, 2 );
my @user3 = ( 2, 1, 4, 3 );

my $data = [ \@user1, \@user2, \@user3 ];
my $field = 3; # Fourth field, perl is 0-based                                           

for my $users ( @$data ) {
    # $users->[...] instead of $users[...] because $users is an array reference             
    if ( $users->[$field] >= 4.0 ) {
        print "first";
    } elsif ( $users->[$field] < 4.0 and $users->[$field] >= 2.5 ) {
        print "second";
    } else {
        print "third";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Output

```
first
third
second
```

Comment: No, don't use `eval` for this kind of task, instead change the data structure and use simply an array of arrayrefs as @zdim already suggested. Just because it is technically possible to do it this way, doesn't mean it should be done this way. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Thanks @dgw.  Updated to a non `eval` version as suggested.  Agreed that simpler is better.